# Why Django 4.0 can access static files only with STATICFILES_DIRS, not STATIC_ROOT

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-4.0

When I use STATIC_ROOT:

```
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'
```

Django cannot access static files and always return 404 error for them.

But when I use STATICFILES_DIRS:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]
```

Everything works well. What's the issue?

I don't understand why Django works in this way, I always thought that STATIC_ROOT is correct way of creating route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`STATIC_ROOT` is where the `collectstatic` command will copy all the static files in.

This folder is meant for production use. So that all the static files in your project (from your apps, or third party apps etc.) are kept in a single folder and therefore becomes easy to serve in production.

---

By default, Django automatically searches for static files inside each app directory (this is helpful in writing reusable apps). The `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting allows you to define extra places to look for the static files.

Also, the `STATIC_ROOT` folder and the `STATICFILES_DIRS` folder should not be the same values.

Comment: and so, STATICFILES_DIRS defines where to find to static files?

Comment: also, why STATICFILES_DIRS should be defined without STATIC_ROOT?

Comment: @DaniiarBiibosunov I've updated the answer with some more details.

Comment: thanks, but I still don't understand why django works only with staticfiles_dirs, not static_root considering fact that they have similar path

Comment: @DaniiarBiibosunov It's doesn't work because `STATIC_ROOT` is not used for serving files. It is just used for keeping all your project's static files in a single place. Read docs for more details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic